# angularJS, ng-options. Make the list lowercase and resort it client side

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a list of options with not optimal data from a client. It now sorts on Capitals first and then lowercase letters. What I would like to accomplish is to first transform all entries to lowercase and then resort it. However I can't get the resorting to work.

My code

```
  <select ng-if='vm.isIe == 11' 
          id="JobTitle" 
          class="form-control customDropdown" 
          ng-model="vm.jobTitleModel" 
          ng-options="vm.departmentModel" 
          ng-options="item  as (item  | lowercase )  for item in  vm.uniqueFields.department | orderBy:(item  | lowercase ) track by item" 
          title="{{item}}" 
          ng-click="vm.loadDropdownValues($event, 'JobTitle')">
```

[image]

Comment: do the sorting and transforming first in your controller then bind it?

Comment: I cannot do that as the data is used for a query string call later on. If I change it beforehand then my value="" attribute will not have the correct data.

Comment: why don't you create two arrays? One for the value attributes and another for what is displayed in the view?